# Opening a pop-up when clicking the help button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'd like to open a pop-up when the Help Button is clicked.

I've got this window with 2 help buttons.

[image: mainWindow]

I want each help button, when pressed, to open a small squared pop-up beside them containing a small text that I've previously written.

What could be the best way to do it ?

I don't want it to be a window, just a square containing some strings.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, maybe you could try looking at this class: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/. It is not exactly what you want but it is very easy to implement.

Comment: @Huunneki Well.. I'm not working on iOS, I'm on OSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`NSPopover`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/). It's fairly easy to implement. There is a sample project [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/samplecode/Popover/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010725).

Comment: I'm trying to implement it today, thanks. Will modify my question if I face some problems.